# Finplot dependency problems. Pyqt 5.15.6 is incompatible

Tags: python, anaconda

Installing finplot i had the following errors.

```
"Spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13 which is not installed"

"Spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqt<5.13 but you have pyqt 5.15.6 which is incompatible"

"Warning: the scripts pylupdate5.exe, pyrcc5.exe and pyuic5.exe are installed in \Users\Paolo\AppData\Roaming\.......\Scripts which is not on PATH.  Consider adding this directory on PATH or if you prefer to suppress this warning use -no-warn-script-location.
```

After that Anaconda Navigator was not launching any more. I had to uninstall Qt5 and install again anaconda.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer and I just bumped `finplot` to use pyqt6 instead, so hopefully that should resolve your issues. Let me know if it doesn't work as expected.